# Creating a JTAppleCalendar inside a xib view

Tags: swift, xcode, jtapplecalendar

I'm trying to create a calendar using JTAppleCalendar inside a xib view because I want a paging type thing for it. On the first page is some information, and the second page is the calendar. I followed the tutorials for JTAppleCalendar on multiple sites, but my project always crashes, probably because I'm doing something wrong.

I have 3 files, a DetailViewController for setting up and displaying the pages, a dataViewController to connect the xib vars, and a CollectionViewCell for the calendar cells.

> DetailViewController

```swift
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var sportName: String = ""
    var numClasses: Int = 0

    var pages : [dataViewController]{
        get {
            let page1: dataViewController = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("dataView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! dataViewController
            page1.label.text = sportName
            page1.classDuration.text = String(numClasses)

            let page2: dataViewController = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("secondDataView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! dataViewController
            page2.calendar.calendarDataSource = self as? JTACMonthViewDataSource
            page2.calendar.calendarDelegate = self as? JTACMonthViewDelegate
            page2.calendar.reloadData()


            return [page1, page2]
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = detailItem {
            if let label = detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.description
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let back = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back",style: .plain,target: self,action: #selector(backButton(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back

        configureView()
        view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)
        setupScrollView(pages: pages)

        pageControl.numberOfPages = pages.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0



    }

    var detailItem: String? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            configureView()
        }
    }

    @objc
    func backButton (_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailToList", sender: self)
    }

    func setupScrollView(pages: [dataViewController]){
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(pages.count), height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        for i in 0 ..< pages.count {
            pages[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * (CGFloat(i)), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            scrollView.addSubview(pages[i])
        }
    }


}

extension DetailViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
    }

}

extension dataViewController: JTACMonthViewDataSource, JTACMonthViewDelegate {

    func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
        formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
        formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
        let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2020 01 01")!
        let endDate = Date()
        return ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTACDayCell {
        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dateCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
        return cell
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, willDisplay cell: JTACDayCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
    }

}
```

> dataViewController

```
import JTAppleCalendar

class dataViewController: UIView {
//Page 1
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var classDuration: UILabel!

//Page 2

    @IBOutlet weak var calendar: JTACMonthView!

}
```

> CollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class CollectionViewCell: JTACDayCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

And of course, the xib files. In DetailViewController, I moved the last extension part to dataViewController, but it didn't change anything. I'm also pretty sure I did many things wrong or inefficiently.

Can anyone help successfully implement the JTAppleCalendar inside the xib view, that would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "*my project always crashes, possibly because I am trying to put it inside a xib.*" Can you post the error message and stack trace?

Comment: @NobodyNada-ReinstateMonica, I have messed around with the project and added a couple of things, but the error currently is "```-[Project.dataViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance```" on the AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 0):

In your DetailViewController You are setting delegate and dataSource of calendar to **self** which is not conforming those protocols.

```
page2.calendar.calendarDataSource = self as? JTACMonthViewDataSource
page2.calendar.calendarDelegate = self as? JTACMonthViewDelegate
```

If thoose are needed to be handled in DetailViewController, I suggest you to start with implementing methods in **DetailViewController** not in **dataViewController**

```
extension DetailViewController: JTACMonthViewDataSource, JTACMonthViewDelegate
```

Comment: I forgot to change the class back, and changed class from dataViewController to DetailViewController. But I need to "set the calendar’s ibCalendarDataSource and ibCalendarDelegate to be the ViewController subclass", and I guess I did it wrong, cause what I wrote before won't do anything, as you said. The error I get now is ```thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x1) ``` in the reloadData() function.